# Complex query - IF ELSE or CASE or both (Replicate part of ETL process)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure how to apporach this query (**The aim of this query is to replicate part of an ETL process, thus validating it**):

When a `bill_type = C or M` and `payer type = C (client) or S (Subsidiary) or T (third party)`

The payer type is defined as follows:

```
If BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO <> HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO for Lead Matter 
and TBM_MATTER._HS_3PTY = 0 Then value = S ('Subsidiary')

If BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO <> HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO for Lead Matter 
and TBM_MATTER._HS_3PTY = 1 Then value = T ('Third Party')

If BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO = HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO for Lead Matter 
Then value = C (    'Client')
```

and

```
BLT_BILL._HS_CNTYPE = blank
```

Then the transaction code = BC or BS or BT.

A case query would be best:

```
   SELECT CASE BILL_TYPE
          WHEN 'C' THEN 'BC'
          END 
   FROM DBO.SRC_BLT.BILL
```

Below is my attempt to create a query, is there a better way of doing this:

```
     SELECT CASE BILL_TYPE 
    WHEN  'C' THEN 
                    (CASE      
                        WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO <> DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN           
                            CASE DBO.SRC_TBM_MATTER._HS_3PTY             
                                WHEN 0 then 'S'             
                                WHEN 1 then 'T'
                            END 
                        WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO = DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN 'C'
                    END)

     WHEN  'M' THEN 
                    (CASE      
                        WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO <> DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN           
                            CASE DBO.SRC_TBM_MATTER._HS_3PTY             
                                WHEN 0 then 'S'             
                                WHEN 1 then 'T'
                            END 
                        WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO = DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN 'C'
                    END)

     END AS TRANS_CODE              


     FROM DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP, DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER, DBO.SRC_TBM_MATTER, DBO.SRC_BLT_BILL

     AND WHERE _HS_CNTYPE = ''
```

Comment: Seems like a fairly straight-forward CASE clause, although more information (eg. the rest of the query/update) would help.

Comment: I've updated the question, with what I believe should be the basis for the case statement. Correct me if you believe this is incorrect.

Comment: That query looks really wrong - it would link every record on SRC_BLT_BILLP with every record on SRC_HBM_MATTER that had non-matching CLIENT_UNO values, and then union the result with all records from SRC_TBM_MATTER where _HS_3PTY is 0. It looks as though another/other fields should be used to link these tables. Can you include the structure of the tables being queried?

Comment: Updated my question with my attempt at the query, partail success in that query does work. Any input welcomed

Comment: is it possible to specify the following in the same case query line. SELECT CASE WHEN (BILL_TYPE IN ('C','M') AND _HS_CNTYPE = '')

Answer (score 1):

I'd say neither.  I think "procedural" when I see "if" or "case".  SQL works best when it's set-based and declarative.

Unless this is a stored procedure, I'd rework this to eliminate "if" and "case".  Just my opinion.

If there are disparate data sets for each bill and player type, maybe you can access them as views and eliminate this logic from your queries.

Comment: This is not SP, rather part of query used to replaicate part of an ETL process. Updated description to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more DRY approach to the CASE clause:

```
 SELECT CASE 
            WHEN BILL_TYPE IN ('C','M') THEN 
                CASE      
                    WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO <> DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN           
                        CASE DBO.SRC_TBM_MATTER._HS_3PTY             
                            WHEN 0 then 'S'             
                            WHEN 1 then 'T'
                        END 
                    WHEN DBO.SRC_BLT_BILLP.PAYR_CLIENT_UNO = DBO.SRC_HBM_MATTER.CLIENT_UNO THEN 'C'
                 END
         END AS TRANS_CODE
```

...